# Give the partition name in the view

Tags: oracle11g

I have created multiple tables, each table having same partition name. To display all tables data in one go, I have created , to do that I have created the view by union all .

```
CREATE VIEW V_TABLES (
      SELECT STATE_ID,STATE_NAME FROM T1 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT STATE_ID,STATE_NAME FROM T2
);
```

both T1 and T2 are partitioned table based on STATE_Name, now I want to fetch the data based on the partition from the view. I don't to change the view each time.

**Note :** Partition name is are same in all the tables.

Comment: Can you post an example of your current query?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Why would you want to specify the partition name in the first place?  Why not query based on the `state_name` and let Oracle figure out which partition to use?

Comment: Purpose is I have JSP page in which I need the data from all the tables based on partition, So I was thinking create a view rather than writing a large query in JSP page. That's why I need the suggestion